# PP relatives with "of which"

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases

I know that *of which*-relatives are always sort of clunky, but are (1a) and (2a) equally acceptable to (1b) and (2b), respectively? Or is there a contrast here?

> (1a) That’s the room, the door of which I kicked open
>
> (1b) That’s the room, the door of which I built wide
>
> (2a) That’s the door, the frame of which I wiped clean
>
> (2b) That’s the door, the frame of which I painted white

Comment: In the words attributed to Wolfgang Pauli: "The examples are so bad, they're not even wrong."  Try *That’s the room **whose** door I kicked open*. or *That's the room, the door of which I kicked open* or "That's the room that I kicked the door open of (colloquial).

Comment: Had a good laugh. Where is this room? Perhaps if I was there, I could have gotten a grammatical insight on these  constructions or I could have.....

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you for your observations. Would you say that you get a contrast between (a) and (b) under the new structures? E.g. do you feel that *That's the room, the door of which I built wide* is worse than *That's the room, the door of which I kicked open*? Or that *That’s the door, the frame of which I painted white* is worse than *That’s the door, the frame of which I wiped clean*?

Comment: @Zoltan All of them sound over-formal for the context. Use "whose" instead of "of which". It is easier to use than "of which".

Comment: @Zoltan, if you're now asking about Greybeard's proposed structures, then please edit your question to show this. If not, this is a side conversation and can be moved to chat.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that (1a) and (2a) might not be as acceptable as (1b) and (2b). What do you think the difference is? (The structures seem identical to me, but I might be missing something.)